# Change structure of data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, transform

This is the current data frame structure

```
value.           blue         red
1                   -1.22049503   -0.62733486
2                    1.61641224   0.43102051
3                    0.09079087   0.61619844
4                    0.32325956   -0.17718356
```

want to change it to

```
value.               number       color
1                   -1.22049503   blue
1                   -0.62733486    red
2                    1.61641224   blue
2                    0.43102051    red
3                    0.09079087   blue
3                    0.61619844    red
4                    0.32325956   blue
4                   -0.17718356    red
```

I saw this question which does the other way. [Transform structure of data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26270850/transform-structure-of-data-frame-in-r)

Comment: `reshape2::melt(data = df1, id.vars = c("value."), variable.name = "color", value.name = "number")`

Comment: @d.b thank you, will this work if there are other columns as well ?

Comment: @johnsmith0 you can test with a head(10) of our dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tidyr::gather` will do it. Assuming the data frame is named `df1`:

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  gather(color, number, -value.)
```

If you want the result ordered by `value.` as in your example, add `dplyr::arrange`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  gather(color, number, -value.) %>%
  arrange(value.)
```

Answer (score -1):

@d.b's comment and @neilfws' answer are great. Here is another way:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  value = c(1, 2, 3),
  blue = c(10, 30, 50),
  red = c(20, 40, 60)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  value = rep(1:nrow(df), each = 2),
  color = rep(c("blue", "red"), nrow(df))
) %>%
  mutate(number = if_else(color == "blue", df$blue[value], df$red[value]))
```

Comment: This creates a data frame from scratch, rather than transforming existing data from wide to long.

Comment: I totally agree but will keep it as it provides some intuition.